# Associating Users and Employees with Rails 5.2 and Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In my applications I have the following situation:
Companys have Users and Employees
Every User is an Employee, but not every Employee is a User (but can be)
What would be the Rails way to implement it?

---

Company.rb

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
  has_many :employees
```

User.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
```

Employee.rb

```
class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
```

Comment: User belongs_to Employee and Employee has_one user.  You can remove company_id column in the users table because the relationship can now be determined as User belongs_to Company through: :employee.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do here is associate employee to company and user to employee, then use a has_many_through to connect company and users.

company.rb

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :employees
  has_many :users, through: :employees
end
```

employee.rb

```
class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
  has_one :user
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :employee
end
```

So, you then can do:

```
> c = Company.create(name: 'Test') # id: 1
> e1 = c.employees.create(name: 'Test1') # id: 1
> e2 = c.employees.create(name: 'Test2') # id: 2
> u = User.create(email: 'test1@test.com', employee_id: 1) # id: 1

> u.employee # <Employee: {id: 1}>
> e1.user # <User: {id: 1}>
> e2.user # nil

> c.employees # [<Employee: {id: 1}>, <Employee: {id: 2}>]
> c.users # [<User: {id: 1}>]
```

Comment: This configuration stops a `User` to have several `Employee`. Putting the foreign key in the `employees` table and use `belongs_to :user, optional: true` would allow OP to eventually switch `has_one :employee` to `has_many :employees` if needed without a DB structure change

Comment: There is no indication that the use case envisions anything other than a one-to-one relationship between users and employees. Since the OP asserted that "Every User is an Employee", putting the foreign key on the users table seemed most appropriate.